# lists of lists in python - treating each internal list of inputs as coordinates iterating mathematical functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

This is a simplified version of the code I am trying to run, but essentially our inputs can be treated as coordinates in their own direction. I only want the operation - in this case the sum - to act between each set of 'coordinates' (internal lists) and then continue iteratively through the 'for-loop' for all values in the input (external list).

From what I can tell, both i and j are changing at the same time, I need to input a 'j' then run through all possible 'i' values before changing to the next j.

Note ### No external packages allowed like numpy or pandas!!

This is the code I have been using

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = []


def summation(one, two):
    for i in list(range(len(one))):
        for j in  list(range(len(two))):
            summ = one[j][i] + two[j]
            c.append(summ)
    print(c)
    
summation(a, b)
```

I have found that the issues lies with the way the function is iterating through the indices i and j.

my DESIRED output is `c = [2, 4, 6,  5, 6, 7,  8, 10, 12]`

I have tried changing the order of the for statements, and the order of the inputs i and j.

From what I can tell, both i and j are changing at the same time, I need to input a 'j' then run through all possible 'i' values before changing to the next j.

Outputs have been the following:

```
# This specific code above gives:
[2, 6, 10, 3, 7, 11, 4, 8, 12]
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to input a 'j' then run through all possible 'i' values before changing to the next j.

This means:

- `for j in ...` must be the outer loop and `for i in ...` must be the inner loop.
- `j` is the index of one of the sublists inside `one`. Then you need `for j in range(len(one)))`, not `for j in range(len(two))`.

  (BTW the `list()` here is unnecessary).
- `i` is the index of a value inside `two`. Then you need `for i in range(len(two))`, not `for i in range(len(one))`.

  And you need `two[i]`, not `two[j]`.
- If you've made these changes, you need to swap the two loops.

The result is:

```
for j in range(len(one)):
    for i in range(len(two)):
        summ = one[j][i] + two[i]
```

(It would have been simpler to swap the meaning of `i` and `j` and then simply fix `one[j][i]` to `one[i][j]`, but I wanted to stick with your original interpretation.)

Instead of fiddling with indices (which as you have seen is error-prone) it is more idiomatic to directly iterate over the values of lists. Then you need the `zip` function to iterate over one of the sublists of `one` and `two` in parallel.

```
for sub_one in one:
    for x, y in zip(sub_one, two):
        summ = x + y
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sublists in *a* are all the same size as *b* then:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
b = [1, 2, 3]

def summation(a, b):
    r = []
    for _a in a:
        r.extend([x+y for x, y in zip(_a, b)])
    return r

print(summation(a, b))
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 4, 6, 5, 7, 9, 8, 10, 12]
```